# The inequality regrading to the outer measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am reading a proof of the following theorem

> In order that the set $\mathbf{A}$ is measurable,it is necessary and sufficient that the following condition be satisfied: For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an elementary set $\mathbf{B}$, such that,
> $$
> \mu^*(A\triangle B)<\epsilon
> $$

In particular the author said to prove the theorem above, we need to show the following lemma

> For two arbitrary sets $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$
> $$
> |\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(B)|\le\mu^*(A\triangle B)
> $$

And he presented the proof of the lemma as follows

> $$
> A\subset B\cup(A\triangle B)
> $$
> So
> $$
> \mu^*(A)\le\mu^*(B)+\mu^*(A\triangle B)
> $$
> if $\mu^*(A)>\mu^*(B)$ and the opposite $\mu^*(B)>\mu^*(A)$ follows the same manner.

I don't understand how he can draw the conclusion that $\mu^*(B)+\mu^*(A\triangle B)$, since doesn't that the addition hold only if the two sets are pairwise disjoint? But in this case, we have $B\cap A\triangle B\neq\emptyset$, so how does he reach the conclusion?

Comment: $A\subset(A\triangle B) \cup B$, subaditivity of the outer measure give and then change the roles of $A$ and $B$

Comment: @OliverDíaz I see! Thanks

Comment: At least one of the sets must have finite outer measure otherwise you are in the situation of $\infty-\infty$ which is not defined.

Comment: Yes, I think the author at the beginning assumes the sets A, B are taken from a square of length 1.